# How to improve application's speed

Tags: android, performance

look at this two methods :

```
//one long single function
public Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, String AssetsFileName) throws IOException {
    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(context.getAssets().open(AssetsFileName));
}

//separate functions
public Bitmap getBitmap(Context context, String AssetsFileName) throws IOException {
    AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
    InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open(AssetsFileName);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
    return bitmap;
}
```

which one is faster or they run same speed ?

second question is more objects will reduce application speed or is it better?

Comment: Both are same. Only difference is number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

That's really no point to use such speed improvements, even if one of the variants will work better - the difference should be minimal. If you are trying to speedup your program - change another part. For example, decoding jpg images is usual faster than decoding png.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) instead, it gives you the powerful of caching images in internal memory. To not decode files all the time when you want to use it. 
You can configure Picasso how much memory it can take, the maximum value.

You can do this actually by your own with some Map object, but then you have to think about releasing Bitmap after use when your app memory consumption is too big. Picasso do this for you.

This is not actually the answer for you straight question, but it could gives you some hint how to handle Bitmaps in your app.